# Pull from remote branch, but do not include the whole history

Tags: php, git, github, ezpublish, ezplatform

I'm using `eZ Platform` open source CMS.
The way you start the project is to create it with `composer`.
After some work, new version comes out and the only way to update it is to `git pull` from github repository, merge it and resolve conflicts.

The whole process is straight forward. Except there is a whole development tree from eZ Plaform available in my own `git repo`.

Is there a way to pull latest commit into the head of certain branch (dev) without pulling all the history since beginning?

Basically I'd like to have it like this:

```
A----B----C----D----E (merge from latest commit on remote branch)
                   /
                  F (basically not even having F in my git tree)
```

Comment: um the whole purpose of composer is so that you don't need to do that ... why can't you just run `php composer update` ?

Comment: Here is the instructions how to update https://doc.ez.no/display/DEVELOPER/Updating+eZ+Platform.
Unfortunately you can't just change the version in composer.

Comment: Oh wow that sucks

Comment: Trying to find a clean way to do it with git.

Comment: Why can't you pull the whole history in a temp branch and then cherry-pick the latest commit(s) on your desired branch? 
```Warning: This is subject to conflicts.```

Comment: Try `git fetch <remote> --depth=<n> <branch>`, with n as 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

quite simple.

you can pull the new version tag in a newly created branch (let's say branch "v1.10" ) and solve all the conflicts there.

after solving the conflicts and having a new version and clean branch you can merge it back into your master with --squash option. 
that way you will not get any of those external trees or commits in your master branch.

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash v1.10
git commit
```

now you have new version in master without any extra commit.